# db_query variable substitution

Tags: database

I'm trying to substitute a variable in a db_query but keep on getting this error:

```
Recoverable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to db_query() must be of the type array, string given
```

It's a single item string that I'm trying to insert:

```
$primary_key = db_query("SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS` WHERE (`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'mydatabase') AND (`TABLE_NAME` = '%s') AND (`COLUMN_KEY` = 'PRI')",$mytable)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I've tried wrapping the variable in an array but then I get no results. **How do I substitute my variable here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal 7 doesn't use the '%' place holders.  Try this:

```
$primary_key = db_query("SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS` WHERE (`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'mydatabase') AND (`TABLE_NAME` = :tbl_name) AND (`COLUMN_KEY` = 'PRI')", array(':tbl_name' => $mytable));
```

Comment: Got a MySQL error on this one.Looks like it's changing the substitution: "('COLUMN_KEY' = 'PRI'); Array ( [:tbl_name] => store ) in"

Comment: this example had single quotes ', instead of ` wrapped around the columns